# Как имитировать клик с помощью ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как имитировать клик на span Upload. На самом деле нажимаю на кнопку submit, но словно на span.

с помощью ref пробовал

```
export default class Loader extends Component {

  state = {
    file: '',
    imagePreviewUrl: ''
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('handle uploading-', this.state.file);
  }

  handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            file: file,
            imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
        });
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={s.uploaderItem}>
            <form  className={s.formUploader} onSubmit={(e)=>this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="fileInput"
                       type="file"
                       onChange={this.handleImageChange} />
                <button className="submitButton"
                        ref={this.ref.click()}
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                >Upload Image
                </button>
            </form>

            <div className={s.uploaderContainer}>
                <div className={s.uploaderContent}>
                    <p>
                        <span className={s.uploadlink}>
                            Upload
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем эмитировать нажатие на span Upload? Судя по вашему коду от этого нажатия ничего не произойдет. Выложите правильный код или сформулируйте правильно вопрос...

Comment: И зачем вы в `onSubmit` передаете функцию, которая ничего не делает при вызове? `onSubmit={(e)=>this.handleSubmit}`

Answer (score 1):

Повести на `span` нужный метод

```
<span onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</span>
```

И так же вызывайте его при отправке формы.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('handle uploading-', this.state.file);
  this.handleUpload();
}
```